# Middleware which lets developer maintain dynamic context

Tags: python, asynchronous, api, websocket

**Problem Statement:** Users can chat while the replies of the chatbot are based on past messages.

So the chatbot needs to have the context of the previous messages and reply accordingly. Here is pseudocode of chatbot for more understanding

```
hi_flag = False
message = await websocket.receive_bytes()
if message == "Hey":
    hi_flag = True
    reply = f'hey, there {user_id}'
    await websocket.send_bytes(reply)
    if message == "hey":
        reply = f'Hey you already said Hi ! WTH !'
        await websocket.send_bytes(reply)

if message == "Goodbye":
    if not hi_flag:
        reply = 'Hey You did not say HI !'
        await websocket.send_bytes(reply)
```

So the problem sums to be pretty much that the user should be able to send a get/post request but the context should be there (like a session)

I am a beginner in this field and this approach won't necessarily be the best. 
Here is a solution that I built using fastapi

---

`invoker.py` *(uvicorn invoker:app)*

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import aioredis
import subprocess

REDIS_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'

app = FastAPI()

client_list = []


async def snoopers_a(client_id):
    client_id += "_replies"
    result = await app.state.r.blpop(client_id)
    return result[1]
    # return str(r.blpop(client_id)[1])[2:-1]


async def pushers_a(client_id, message):
    await app.state.r.lpush(client_id,message)


@app.on_event("startup")
async def on_startup():
    r = await aioredis.create_redis(REDIS_URL)
    app.state.r = r


@app.post("/request")
async def request_startpoint(client_id: str, client_message: str):
    if client_id in client_list:
        print("Waiting at Existing Client")
        await pushers_a(client_id, client_message)
        return await snoopers_a(client_id)

    else:

        client_list.append(client_id)
        print("Creating new Subprocess !")
        subprocess.Popen(['python', 'arbiter.py', client_id])
        print("Subprocess Created !")
        await pushers_a(client_id, client_message)
        print(f"Waiting for {client_id}")
        return await snoopers_a(client_id)
```

The above invokes a new python process for each client. ( The invoked process from here on arbiter). It also pushes the messages in a Redis list. The task of the arbiter is to get the message from the list and then send it to the connected WebSocket to push the reply back in a reply list of that client. The invoker after pushing the message would just wait at the reply list and the rest work is done by the invoker.

---

`arbiter.py`

```
import asyncio
import aioredis
import websockets
import sys

client_id = sys.argv[1]
print(sys.argv[1])


async def snoopers_b(client_id,r):
    result = await r.blpop(client_id)
    return result


async def pushers_b(client_id, message,r):
    client_id += "_replies"
    await r.lpush(client_id, message)


async def websockets_thing(client_id):
    REDIS_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
    r = await aioredis.create_redis(REDIS_URL)
    uri = "ws://localhost:1111/ws"
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as babble_socket:
        while True:
            client_message = await snoopers_b(client_id, r)
            print(f"Got Message of Client : {client_message}")
            await babble_socket.send(client_message)
            bot_message = await babble_socket.recv()
            print(f"Got Message of Babble : {bot_message}")
            if bot_message == "BYE":
                await r.delete(client_id)
                break
            await pushers_b(client_id, bot_message, r)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(websockets_thing(client_id))
loop.close()
```

The task of the arbiter is client-specific. It invokes a new connection so that it gets the message from the client_queue and then pushes it to connected WebSocket, gets a reply back and pushes reply back to middleware/invoker.

---

`dummychatbot.py` runs at port 1111 *(uvicorn dummychatbot:app --port 1111)*

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.websockets import WebSocket
import random

app = FastAPI()


@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    id = random.randint(10, 10000)
    while True:
        data = await websocket.receive_bytes()
        if data == "Hey":
            print(f"Hey User {id} : {data} Acknowledged :P")
            await websocket.send_bytes(f"Hey User {id} : {data} Acknowledged :P")

            data = await websocket.receive_bytes()
            if data == "Hello" :
                print(f"Hey User {id} : you already said Hey :P")
                await websocket.send_bytes(f"Hey User {id} : {data} Acknowledged :P")

        else:
                print(f"Hey User {id} : Start with Hey instead of {data} :P")
                await websocket.send_bytes(f"Hey User {id} : {data} Acknowledged :P")
```

A chatbot is the main hurdle. The above two programs are created so that context can be maintained using get and post requests. So if the user has previously said Hey and now says Hello it gets reply accordingly.

> I tried getting rid of WebSockets here but it faces deadlock problem
>   does not work for more than one clients concurrently
>   Middleware API : https://paste.pythondiscord.com/abopimehik.py
>   Chatbot Independent: https://paste.pythondiscord.com/odakitoteg.py

---

***Benchmarks***

The above code works for 900 concurrent users after that either there is Redis garbage collector error or server gets forced disconnected. Tested using this code: https://paste.pythondiscord.com/exomobelaz.py

Comment: In your `dummychatbot.py` script --> 2 `if` statements: how do you imagine `data` be simultaneously `data == "Hey"` AND `data == "Hello"` ???

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I have edited the code it was a minor error while copy-pasting. I have added one more recieve_bytes(). So that It can act as a dummy of keeping the context.